# Looking for a better automatic task scheduler like Motion

Tags: calendar, task-management, google-calendar

I'm interested in finding an automatic task scheduler that better fits my needs.
This basically tasks a task list with priorities and deadlines and automatically schedules in on Google Calendar in the optimal order.

Currently I'm using https://www.usemotion.com/ but it is extremely slow, glitchy, and I have to report bugs daily.

The features I like are:

- one-time tasks **auto reschedule** when you don't complete them
- tasks are given priorities and deadlines and scheduled accordingly
- follows rules like "schedule during work hours" or some custom schedule

Cons:

- extremely slow, checking off a task should feel good not anxious because it registers my click so slowly
- glitchy (task notes and events are sometimes deleted randomly)
- priority levels for one-time vs recurring tasks don't match. Recurring have: high and medium priority while one-time tasks have: ASAP, high, medium, low.
- no way to prevent recurring task rollover when I don't complete a recurring task. Not sure if this is a bug or intended behavior. Recurring tasks need an option to rollover or not.
- developers seem focused on adding team features (like asana) instead of fixing core scheduling functionality
- syncing between work and personal calendar causes motion tasks to clutter actual gcal with duplicate `[busy] motion task` entries